# how does the magic store commands for dataframe work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I created two dataframes (df1 and df2) in two jupyter notebooks (N1 and N2) respectively.

On day 1, I used the below store command to use the `df1` and its variables in `N2` jupyter notebook

```
%store -r df1
```

But on day 25, I created a new jupyter notebook `N3` and used the below store command again

```
%store -r df1
```

And it seemed to easily pull all the details of dataframe `df1` into `N3` jupyter notebook easily?

How does this work?

Aren't they valid only for that specific jupyter notebook session?

Then instead of storing all dataframes as files, can we just execute a store command and store/retrieve them easily anytime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Storemagic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html) is an IPython feature that "Stores variables, aliases and macros in IPython’s database".  Because it is an IPython feature rather than exclusive to Jupyter you can store and restore variables across many IPython and Jupyter sessions.

In my environment (IPython 7.19.0) the variables get stored in the directory:

```
$HOME/.ipython/profile_default/db/autorestore
```

They are stored one per file when stored using `%store <name>`.  The files themselves are the [pickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) representation of the stored variables.  You could manually load the variables by using the following:

```py
import pickle

# Name of the previously stored variable
stored_var = 'test'

# myvar will contain the variable previously stored with "%store test"
myvar_filename = get_ipython().ipython_dir + '/profile_default/db/autorestore/' + stored_var
with open(myvar_filename, 'rb') as f:
    myvar = pickle.load(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`%store`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html) magic command stores variables in IPython’s database (it's essentially using pickle at the backend to store) so that you recover it later across separate notebooks or sessions.

e.g.

```
>>> myvar = "store this string"
>>> %store myvar
Stored 'myvar' (str)
>>> %store
Stored variables and their in-db values:
myvar             -> 'store this string'
```

Now, you can recover this variable

```
>>> %store -r myvar
>>> myvar
'store this string'
```